# ajax refuses to submit data for processing to php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Although, am new to ajax and am trying to submit data for processing and insertion into the database using php but it could not work and I don't why and these are the steps taking so far.
1. Using php alone, am able to insert data into the database an d this is the php code.

```
<?php
        try {
            $linkas = 2;
            require_once 'db/DBConnect.php';
            $errors = [];
            $good = true;
            if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && !empty($_POST['testimony'])):
                $testimony = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'testimony', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

                if (strlen($testimony) < 20):
                    //report error and do not go
                    $errors[] = 'It has to be more than 20 characters' . '<br>';
                    $good = false;
                else:
                    $good = true;
                    if ($good):
                        $insertTestimony = 'INSERT INTO testimony(content, j_member_id, time_send) ';
                        $insertTestimony .= 'VALUES (:testimony, :user_id, NOW())';
                        $insert = $conn1->prepare($insertTestimony);
                        $insert->bindValue(':testimony', $testimony, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                        $insert->bindValue(':user_id', $linkas, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                        $insert->execute();
                        if ($insert->rowCount() == 1):
                            //success message
                            $_SESSION['msg'] = 'Thanks for the testimony';
                            header('Location: index.php');
                            exit();
                        else:
                            //fail message
                            echo 'Something is wrong, please resubmit';
                        endif;
                    endif;
                endif;
            endif;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo 'Database error: ' . $e->getMessage() . ' in ' . $e->getFile() . ':' . $e->getLine();
        }
        ?>
```

After testing the php and seeing that it works, I proceeded to create the html page which is below

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <section class="">
            <article>
                <div id="testifyForm">
                    <form action="" method="post" id="testimony" accept-charset="utf-8">
                        <fieldset>
                            <legend>Your testimony</legend>
                            <label for="testimony"></label>
                            <textarea id="testimony" name="testimony" maxlength="300"></textarea>
                        </fieldset>
                        <input type="submit" name="testify" id="testify" value="Testify">
                    </form>
                </div>
            </article>
        </section>
        <script src="js/ajax.js"></script>
        <script src="js/testify.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Finally, I created the ajax.js script and testify.js script and placed them inside the js folder and link them to the html which you can see above.

This is the testify script

```
function validateForm() {
    'use strict';
    var testimony = document.getElementById('testimony');
    if ((testimony.value.length > 20)) {
        var ajax = getXMLHttpRequestObject();

        ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (ajax.readyState == 4) {
                if ((ajax.status >= 200 && ajax.status < 300) || (ajax.status == 300)) {
                    //return ajax.responseText
                    document.getElementById('testifyForm').innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
                } else {
                    document.getElementById('theForm').submit();
                    //return ajax.statusText
                }//End of status
                ajax = null;
            }//End of readyState
        };//End of onreadystatechange
        //return true;
        ajax.open('POST', 'empty.php', true);
        ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        var data = 'testimony=' + encodeURIComponent(testimony.value);
        ajax.send(data);
        return false;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = 'Characters must be more than 20 words';
        return false;
    }//End of testimony
}

function init() {
    'use strict';
    if (document && document.getElementById) {
        var testifyForm = document.getElementById('testifyForm');
        testifyForm.onsubmit = validateForm;
    }
}

window.onload = init;
```

And this is the ajax script

```
function getXMLHttpRequestObject() {
    var ajax = null;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // Older IE.
        ajax = new ActiveXObject('MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0');
    }
    return ajax;
}
```

The problem now is that ajax refuses to submit those data for processing and saving(which I believe PHP should handle). 
I also tried debugging it if there is any error by checking the console with ctrl+shift+j on chrome(that is the only step taken so far about debbuging)

P.s. This is pure JavaScript and ajax not jquery

Comment: `testifyForm = document.getElementById('testifyForm')`,`<div id="testifyForm">` you are putting the submit event on the div, not the form

Comment: debug your issue using `debugger;` in your javascript.

Comment: @PatrickEvans That is what I saw in the example that am following

Comment: Suggestions: a) in your browser, try opening the Debugger Tools (usually F12), tab "network" and see exactly what it's being sent. b) try to report in php what it's being recieved: `print_r($_POST); die();` and check the output of that in debugger tools.

Comment: @DamiánPabloGonzález using the debugger tool in chrome, the STAT for the 3 scripts showed 200(meaning 'ok'), the TIME says 152ms while pending for both JavaScript script

Comment: @gbengawale, I meant the `Query String Parameters` (at the bottom of tab Headers) to see what is sent,  or `Response` tab to see what is returning from php when you add the `print_r($_POST);`

Comment: @DamiánPabloGonzález from what I saw in firebug, am sending a POST request but is returning a GET request

Answer (score 0):

Check in your code to see if `data` is defined. In your code you have `ajax.send(data);` but I don't see where you have defined the payload POST data.

In your PHP don't be afraid to use `print_r($_SERVER)` to see what is being sent in your request. Also in Chrome you can inspect element and see all of the errors you JavaScript is having as well as watch what requests are made and what data is being sent.

Comment: This is payload 'ajax.open('POST', 'empty.php', true);'

Comment: `ajax.open` is just creating an instance of the Ajax element with the POST method going to empty.php and specifying that you want it to be asynchronous.

`ajax.send(data)` is sending your request and appending `data` as the body of your POST Request. (`data` being your payload.)

Comment: Check the console and see if you are getting any errors, and check the network tab to see if you getting all of the data you want sent.

Comment: Ok Try adding this to the top of your file
`print_r($_SERVER);`
This will display all of the input on the request.